# SSRS Issue : Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to configure SSRS report on web server whose data source is cube and we are using com component to access the data from analysis server cube.

I am getting below error when I run the report from UI(web server locally).

> System.Reflection. TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0E7A): **Provider
>   cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.**

Below is the detail of installed SQL Server versions

> **SQL Version on Web server** : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6529.0 (X64)   Mar 19 2015 13:19:13   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build
>   9600: ) (Hypervisor)
>
> **SQL Version on AS server** : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build
>   9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: What do you mean by using a COM component? Isn't the SSAS driver already fully installed? I suggest you log on to your SSRS server and confirm that the SSAS driver is installed.

Comment: Com components can be considered as dll's. And yes, SSAS driver are installed. Also, our web server and ssrs server is same.

Comment: Yes COM components are compiled to DLL's (or for an out of process component it is compiled to an EXE). I don't know if this is relevant here. The error message indicates that it thinks the driver is not installed.

Comment: So if you create a .UDL file you can see the SSAS provider on your SSRS server? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/

Comment: Yes Nick, I do see Microsoft OLEDB Provider for Analysis Services 10.0 and sql server native client 10.0 is present on AS server as well

Comment: It could be a 32/64 bit thing or it could be that it's not running on the server you think it is. Is IIS and SSRS installed on the same machine?

Comment: Yes Nick. Both are on the same machine.

Comment: So when you build the report (in Visual Studio?) it connects OK and previews without errors?

Comment: Actually I am migrating the reports from win 2003 to 2012 servers.

Comment: Is it the same version of SSAS and SSRS? How are you migrating them? Do you migrate without errors then click on the report and get the error? What happens if you go and find the actual data source inside the web portal and test it? What happens if you create a brand new data source in the web portal?

Comment: Yes. Version is same for SSAS and SSRS. Not tried testing the data source connection. Let me see if this is possible because I have not found any solution of these reports yet.

Comment: Here's a guide to testing data sources in SSRS. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtd3BwXqeY4 I guess you'll get the same error but the *real* test is when you create a brand new datasource.

Comment: Thank you Nick. Will update the solution if I find one.

Comment: Did you manage to create a brand new connection? Did it work? is it different to the failing connection?

Comment: the connection is made through com component and com is working fine after doing test.

Comment: So it sounds like you did not go into the SSRS portal and try to create a new connection. If you have an answer that could help anyone else who has come across this issue, please post so it can help everyone.

Comment: I am getting this error now. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040E21): Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Comment: Getting it where? When you run a report, when you test the connection, or when you try and create a new connection?

Comment: when I run the report. Error is captured in eventvwr.

Comment: I suggest you try and create a brand new connection inside the SSRS portal, and test it. If it works, compare it to the connection that doesn't work. Don't try and troubleshoot this from the report, troubleshoot it from the actual connection that the report uses inside the SSRS portal.

Comment: Fix for this issue is to change the provider from SQLNCLI.1 to SQLNCLI10.1 in connection string of service.

Comment: Thanks for returning with a solution. Why don't you put it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I'm curious - did you  discover that when you created a new connection and compared it to the existing connection? That's what I suggested for you to do five times

Comment: Actually, there was nothing I can compare it with. But thanks for advice and help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the SQL Provider from SQLNCLI.1 to SQLNCLI10.1 in connection string of service to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Connection string somewhere in you project, there must be a
**"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"""** in you Connection string. if you are installed all component perfectly with all drivers then you might forgot to add the provider name in your Connection String